# Finding a heading towards a coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have my location (coordinate) and my heading (compass) and am trying to calculate the heading towards a given other coordinate, so that I can show an arrow on screen pointing towards that location. What I'm building is basically a glorified compass that doesn't point north, but towards a specific coordinate, so it will need to take into account the bearing towards that coordinate and the user's compass heading.

I was expecting CoreLocation to contain the necessary building blocks for this, but aside from getting the distance between two coordinates, there doesn't appear to be anything there.

Unfortunately my tries of manually calculating this haven't been very fruitful and it's hard to guess where I'm going wrong. I've since tried adapting what I found [here](https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/), and I get the same results for the sample data there, but it goes totally awry as soon as I use my own coordinates.

```swift
extension Double {
    var radians: Double {
        self * .pi / 180
    }
}


let A = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.0295437, longitude: 13.7277793)
let B = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.026819, longitude: 13.726348)

let ΔL = abs(A.longitude) - abs(B.longitude)
let X = cos(B.latitude.radians) * sin(ΔL.radians)
let Y = cos(A.latitude.radians) * sin(B.latitude.radians) - sin(A.latitude.radians) * cos(B.latitude.radians) * cos(ΔL.radians)
let bearing = atan2(X, Y)
let heading = bearing - userHeading
```

Once I incorporate the device's heading into this (the substraction at the end) it appears as if my values are somehow flipped along the W-E-axis (pointing left instead of right and the other way around), but the N-S-axis appears to be correct. The calculation of the bearing must be off somehow.
I really don't have much knowledge regarding geocoordinate systems.

Comment: I take it you've converted `userHeading` to radians?

Comment: I have, yes. I used SwiftUI's `Angle` type for this after the calculation here, but yeah.

Comment: Where are you getting `userHeading` from? Is this the value stored in the `heading` property belonging to `MKMapCamera` or the value stored in the`heading` property of a `CLLocationManager` instance?

Comment: It's the value from a `CLLocationManager`. The values definitely appear to be correct and show my compass heading.

Comment: "The values definitely appear to be correct and show my compass heading" so what exactly is the issue? I mean basically you're just trying to build an ordinary compass except that the needle points to some given bearing instead of zero. And building an ordinary compass is easy. And you say you know the desired bearing. So you're all set.

Comment: The heading values from the `CLLocationManager` are correct, however my calculation of the destination coordinate bearing is not. That is the part I'm experiencing issues with and the code shown above which apparently isn't doing what I hoped it should.

Comment: I've added some more information to the question to further describe the issue I'm experiencing. Sorry for not being clear enough before.

Comment: Yes, the earth is not flat; sorry about that. "however my calculation of the destination coordinate bearing is not" Did you get it from https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/ ?

Comment: Yes, that is the calculation I believe to have adapted. I do get the same result for the example coordinates shown there, but as said above, it goes completely awry when plugging in my own coordinates and I have no clue why. Could it be due to my longitude values not being negative like in the US? Although I guess that shouldn't have any effect? My only other guess is that everything is working fine and subtracting the device heading is just downright wrong, but I don't *think* so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try it this way. First I need to establish some conversions:

```
extension Double {
    var toRadians : Double {
        var m = Measurement(value: self, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
        m.convert(to: .radians)
        return m.value
    }
    var toDegrees : Double {
        var m = Measurement(value: self, unit: UnitAngle.radians)
        m.convert(to: .degrees)
        return m.value
    }
}
```

Now I'll make a formula; `a` is where I am, `b` is the distant point whose bearing I want:

```
let a = // some CLLocationCoordinate2D
let b = // some CLLocationCoordinate2D

let deltaL = b.longitude.toRadians - a.longitude.toRadians
let thetaB = b.latitude.toRadians
let thetaA = a.latitude.toRadians
let x = cos(thetaB) * sin(deltaL)
let y = cos(thetaA) * sin(thetaB) - sin(thetaA) * cos(thetaB) * cos(deltaL)
let bearing = atan2(x,y)
let bearingInDegrees = bearing.toDegrees
print(bearingInDegrees) // sanity check
```

Now I'll test some actual bearings. I'll give `a` and `b` followed by what was printed (`bearingInDegrees`). I'll start with the page we got the formula from:

```
let a = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.099912, longitude: -94.581213)
let b = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  38.627089, longitude: -90.200203)
// 96.51262423499941, yep, that's the answer given on example page
```

Okay, that worked. Now I'll try myself and some points in various directions from me:

```
let a = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.439931, longitude: -119.263984)
let b = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.489290, longitude: -119.221670)
// 35 degrees, about right

let a = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.439931, longitude: -119.263984)
let b = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.484479, longitude: -119.308273)
// -40 degrees, about right
        
let a = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.439931, longitude: -119.263984)
let b = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.376978, longitude: -119.329645)
// -139, about right
```

Okay, let's try it in some other location, where longitude values are positive:

```
let a = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.518044, longitude: 13.374602) // Berlin
let b = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.444748, longitude: 14.534668) // Szczecin
// 36, looks good to me
```

Fine! Now let's fill in the last piece of the puzzle, namely the bearing given the way I am actually facing. I think in degrees, so let's keep using degrees. I'll take the last result as an example. I'm in Berlin but now I'm facing east. Call the top of my device zero. What angle should the needle point, in order to point to Szczecin?

```
let myHeading = 90.0 // (I'm facing east)
let bearingFromMe = bearingInDegrees - myHeading
print(bearingFromMe) // -53, sounds good
```

`-53` means forward and to my left. Sure enough, I'm facing east, so that's the direction we want to go.

Comment: I've just reproduced this in a small sample app and everything appears to be working. But this is... the same thing I've been doing, isn't it? Am I going mad?  There must be some other issue, but huge thanks for helping me see the light! I'm going to take another look at this tomorrow and try and find where I've been going wrong.

Comment: Well you were defining your `ΔL` completely wrong for one thing. — But the key thing here is my methodology; (a) I paid no attention to what you had written, and (b) I did a lot of sanity tests. So if I'm doing it right, thats why. I can't guarantee that it's right, but at least I seem to be getting a lot of right answers so far.

Comment: Ah, you're right. And I should definitely work on my problem solving methodology, checking everything along the way sounds very sensible. Thanks again 

Comment: I was just making a small app and it worked for me. Thank you!